# LSI SAS 1064E drivers for Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, lsi

I have a need to place Windows Server 2012 onto a Sunfire X4100 blade server that contains a LSI SAS 1064e RAID controller (2006).  The LSI site only has drivers up to server 2008 R2.

I did attempt to install server 2012 hoping it might contain generic MS Drivers (I was dreaming, I know).  That failed.  I attempted to load external LSI drivers for server 2008.  That failed as well.

Am I out of luck, or did I miss something?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't use the 2008 drivers, Microsoft doesn't have the drivers bundled in, and LSI themselves haven't provided any drivers for 2012, you're out of luck until one of those three venues offers up drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck.  From my exchange with LSI over exactly this issue:

> Windows 2012 is not supported. The chip has been OEL'd so we will not
>   software updates for it.
>
> You can download the latest software here:
>   http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS1068E.aspx
>
> Thanks

To get around this we're bypassing the RAID controller direct to a SATA port on the motherboard.

Comment: link is bad.  also could not figure out how to bypass raid controller on an HP Z800.

Answer (score -2):

That's strange, I have a HP LSI 1064E based controller and it can be detected by either 2008R2 and 2012R2 out of the box.

Although, the server is a HP ProLiant ML350G5.

[image]